# xaml: Is there a method to implement OR logic in multiple triggers?

Tags: xaml, role, multitrigger

I want the Role to be either TopLevelHeader **OR** TopLevelItem as well as IsPressed.  Is this possible without specifying two MultiTriggers?

```
<MultiTrigger>

  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>

  <!--  IsPressed   -->
  <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
  <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader"/>

  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" .../>

</MultiTrigger>
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charlie Robbins has posted an article on [How to use a MultiTrigger with an "or" condition](http://www.charlierobbins.com/articles/2009/03/16/wpf-tips-how-to-use-a-multitrigger-with-an-or-condition/):

> MultiTrigger (and MultiDataTrigger)
>   both take have a property called
>   'Conditions' of type
>   ConditionCollection. Each Condition
>   object within these
>   ConditionCollections can be used in
>   one of two ways:
>
> 1. You can set the Property and Value properties to setup an ordinary
>      property condition.
> 2. You can set the Binding and Value properties to setup a data condition.
>
> Now if you want to accomplish an or
>   condition in either case you will
>   actually use a MultiDataTrigger. The
>   gotcha here is that we can use the
>   Binding property of the Condition
>   class in conjunction with a
>   MultiValueConverter to get the desired
>   behavior... [read more](http://www.charlierobbins.com/articles/2009/03/16/wpf-tips-how-to-use-a-multitrigger-with-an-or-condition/)

He's posted a [sample solution](http://github.com/indexzero/wpf-samples) as well.

Comment: I managed to get it to work but I'm a little hesitant to implement it in fear of the fallout from maintenance monkeys.  Wait, that's me.  To hell with me, it's going in! <g>  Thanks Again

Comment: As a fellow maintenance monkey, err smurf, I fling my little blue poo at you! :P